# C - Visually Efficient Pointer Array Initialization Using {}

Tags: c, pointers

Is there a way to do something like the array initialization braces method for a pointer array?

```
myStruct* array = malloc(4*sizeof(myStruct));
array = {a,b,c,d}; //like this
```

The reason I'm interested is because the aforementioned lines are much nicer to look at than:

```
myStruct* array = malloc(4*sizeof(myStruct));
array[0] = blah0;
array[1] = blah1;
array[2] = blah2;
...
array[n] = blahn;
```

The variables I'm initializing to are variables passed as function arguments so I'm unable to efficiently iterate through them to initialize the array...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do it with C99. The feature is called "compound literals".

```
struct tag {
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
};

struct tag *t;
t = &(struct tag){1, 2, 3};
```

Or, for arrays:

```
int *arr;
arr = (int []) {1, 2, 3};
```

Comment: I'm using GCC on OS X. I think this fragment of C99 compatibly is not included for me as it will not compile. Thank you for the useful reply though!

Comment: Yep, no luck... gcc -o -std=c99 prog prog.c

Comment: Oops, typo in my response. Yes, I did the latter.

Comment: I just tried in Xcode 4.1. It compiles using LLVM GCC 4.2, GCC 4.2 and the Apple LLVM compiler 2.1. `int *arr; arr = (int[]){1, 2, 3};`

Answer (score 0):

If this is really about constant sized data as you indicate in your example, you probably simply shouldn't use `malloc` for it. C has arrays, use them :)

```
myStruct array[4] = {a,b,c,d};
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but use them only needed:

```
myStruct array[] = {a,b,c,d};
```